# Getting the value of returned json using a known key

Tags: php, jquery

I have this php code that returns some json

```
public function my_account(){
             header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
           $email_posted = $this->input->post('email');
           $email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email_posted);

            $where = "email='$email'";

            $this->db->where($where);


            $query = $this->db->get('users');

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               foreach ($query->result() as $row)
               {
                  $json = array("id"=>$row->id, "email"=>$row->email,"names"=>$row->names,"country"=>$row->country,"password"=>$row->password,"telephone"=>$row->telephone);
                  echo json_encode($json);
               }
            }

         }
```

The json returned is of this format

`{"id":"15","email":"corn64@gmail.com","names":"Cern 64","country":"","password":"cern!768","telephone":"00000"}`

To get the data in jquery

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        alert(obj.email);
});
```

and has this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c5b4o6yh/2/

I get the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in`

> {"id":"15","email":"corn64@gmail.com","names":"Cern
>   64","country":"","password":"cern!768","telephone":"00000"}

What is the right way to get the value using the known keys?.

Comment: `alert(data.email)` as `data` is a simple object.

Comment: Here you have a string. Either `json.parse` it to get json object, or remove `'` from the beginning and the end of the string.

Comment: Done. See the edited question.

Comment: __Answer__ the question. Writing updates in a question is useless.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help. I have removed the updates which strangely some asked for.

Comment: you just need to parse the data here is updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/sain_anky/c5b4o6yh/5/

Comment: @AnkitKumar  if he used `dataType:'json',` in his code (ajax) then parsing will not needed (automatically done by jquery)

Comment: use this, first parse the data and then get the value of email.

var data = '{"id":"15","email":"corn64@gmail.com","names":"Cern 64","country":"","password":"cern!768","telephone":"00000"}';
 var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 alert(data['email']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is for-sure a problem:-***

1.You are over-writing your `$json` variable inside `foreach()`

2.You are sending only single response inside `foreach()`.

Change code like below (changes are commented):-

```
public function my_account(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    $email_posted = $this->input->post('email');
    $email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email_posted);

    $where = "email='$email'";

    $this->db->where($where);


    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $json = array(); //define variable as an array variable
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
          $json []= array("id"=>$row->id, "email"=>$row->email,"names"=>$row->names,"country"=>$row->country,"password"=>$row->password,"telephone"=>$row->telephone);//assign values to array

       }
    }
    echo json_encode($json); // send response after loop completion
 }
```

Now your original script code will work.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you save the values in an array.((with array_push() function you can inserts one or more elements to the end of an array))

```
public function my_account(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    $email_posted = $this->input->post('email');
    $email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email_posted);

    $where = "email='$email'";

    $this->db->where($where);


    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $json = array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
        array_push($json,array("id"=>$row->id, "email"=>$row->email,"names"=>$row->names,"country"=>$row->country,"password"=>$row->password,"telephone"=>$row->telephone));

          echo json_encode($json);
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your response should be array, not a simple object. So, try to rework your code to return

```
[{"id":"15","email":"corn64@gmail.com","names":"Cern 64","country":"","password":"cern!768","telephone":"00000"}]
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5b4o6yh/4/) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert the JSON string from your endpoint into a JS Object, then get the individual key values:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var id = obj.id;
```